# Oauth2 Data from Google after authorization

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

While learning about Google Oauth2, I saw two options for implementation

Option 1) Using PHP client library installed locally on server
example - http://phppot.com/php/php-google-oauth-login/

Option2) Using Javascript, AJAX, PHP & the google platform library (from CDN directly)
example - http://w3lessons.info/2015/05/19/google-oauth-2-0-ajax-login-using-jquery-php-mysql/

I have been able to implement both. However I have following questions:

Question 1) 
In option 1 `[$profile = $this->client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();]` gives me profile data which contains only `email[email]` & `google ID[sub]`.

Output: of `$profile`

```
Array
(
    [envelope] => Array
        (
            [alg] => R256
            [kid] => ca6f0ece055ffa823454e56da
        )

    [payload] => Array
        (
            [iss] => accounts.google.com
            [at_hash] => e5l-tvQpWQ
            [aud] => 8pps.googleusercontent.com
            [sub] => 186524872
            [email_verified] => 1
            [azp] => 1go.apps.googleusercontent.com
            [email] => sagl@gmail.com
            [iat] => 14543
            [exp] => 14543
        )

)
```

In option 2 `[var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();]` gives me a profile data which contains the full name & the profile picture link on top of google ID & email

Is there any function which can get me the Profile name & picture link using option 1 (only PHP based implementation)

Question 2) For option 2 how can I modify the default "Google button" logo being sent by Google through the div:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-longtitle="true" data-onsuccess="Google_signIn" data-theme="light" data-width="200"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: $profile['payload'] now has an additional key named picture and its value is a URL to the profile picture.

Question 2: There are a limited number of attributes you can use to customize your sign-in button: data-scope, width, height, data-longtitle, data-theme, data-onsuccess, and data-onfailure. data-scope is used to request permission scopes. data-longtitle takes a true or false(default) value to determine whether you want to display "sign in with google" or "sign in", respectively. data-theme takes values light or dark. And data-onsuccess and data-onfailure take js functions to be called on successful/failed sign in attempts.

Beyond that, you'll have to do some reading to really customize the button here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#customizing_the_automatically_rendered_sign-in_button_recommended